# Way to achieve backwards compatibility from PHP 5.3 to 5.2 (Pre processor directive?)

Tags: php, closures, php-5.3, backwards-compatibility, php-5.2

I have written a cool little PHP library but it makes use of closures which cause a PARSE ERROR (not a runtime error!) when I run the app on my webhost (1and1). What I would love is something like a c++ preprocessor directive or an CSS version-specific comment that basically ignores a segment of code for PHP < 5.3

```
$this->register_validator(
    function($val) use ($length_expr)
    { 
        $x = strlen($val);
        return eval("return $x $length_expr;");
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't know how you'd get around a parse error within the same file, but you could put the "offending" code in a separate file and only require() it if phpversion() is >= 5.3 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)

Comment: Can you not just get a better webhost? 5.2 is no longer even maintained. It's dead. Any webhosts not providing 5.3 is not a good webhost.

Comment: I actually came up with the same solution juand, EXCEPT this leads to another problem because this particular code is in a class method declaration (which unlike c/c++ seems to need to have definitions and declarations be in the same file). I could have the method call a global function defined one of two ways using includes based on version, but this felt so ugly and hacky that I thought there MUST be something better....

Ultimately I have used the workaround of using a trick to get my webhost to use a beta of PHP 6.0, but frankly I'm majorly disappointed with the host.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a syntax error, which causes the parse error in the eval()'d code.

I tried it in PHP 5.2.17 and 5.3.6 too:

You can not return two values inmediately, like this:

```
return $x $legth_expr;
```

This is throwing a parse error in the mentioned two versions.

What do you want to achieve exactly?